When can I just take complex inverses in absolute value inequalities?
For example, consider the inequality $\left|\sin z\right| < a$. Why is it correct to take $\left|z\right| < \arcsin a$ (restricting $-\pi < |z| < \pi$)? Is it a property of complex $\sin$, or does it apply to other functions too?

This definitely depends on the function, but your example is wrong! If you have $|\sin z|<a$ and take $a=\frac12$, taking $|z|<\arcsin a$ would mean $|z|<0.523599\dots$ so that would allow $z=\frac12i$, but then $|\sin z|=\sinh\frac12=0.521095\dots$, so that's no longer a solution of $|\sin z|<a$.
If on the other hand, we look at
$$
|\sinh z| < a
$$
then we can indeed allow $z$-values where $|z|<\text{arcsinh}\, a$. It is allowed for those functions that are larger on the real axis than in any other direction of the complex plane at the same distance. $\sinh$ is such a function (which you probably meant to use!) while $\sin$ is not.
